Structure of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ with given property
Let $G$ be a finite group and $A\leq \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Assume that $‎P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $z\in Z(P)$ of order $p$ such that each ‎subgroup of order $p$ of $P$ is $A$-conjugate to $\left\langle z\right\rangle‎ ‎$‎. Can we prove that $N_{GA}(P)$ acts transitively on the set of subgroups of order $p$ of $Z(P)$?
Moreover, can we conclude that $P$ is either homocyclic‎ ‎or generalized quaternion or $2$-automorphic $2$-group‎?

In your question is each subgroup of $G$ of order $p$ $A$-conjugate to $\langle z\rangle,$ or did you mean each subgroup of $P$ or of $Z(P)$?

@Tom WIlde: each subgroup of $P$

@Geoff Robinson: Thank you for your comment. Would it be possible for you to explain more about the fusion results of Burnside/Alperin?

Burnside proved that if $X$ is any finite group and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $X$ then two elements of $Z(P)$ are conjugae in $X$ if and only if they are conjugate in $N_{X}(P).$ As Alperin noted, the argument works equally well with subgroups of $Z(P)$. In any case, the direct argument of @TomWilde is better, and my comment becomes irrelevant.

Hello @TomWIlde, nice to see you here!

Hi @NeilStrickland - nice to see you too (often in the top questions, which I wish I could answer :) Hope all's well.

No.  It's harder than that.

I think the first part is correct as stated, by the Burnside argument. Let $V=\langle z\rangle,$ and let $W$ be a subgroup of order $p$ of $Z(P).$ Since in particular $W\subseteq P,$ there is $a\in A$ such that $V^a=W.$ Then $V$ centralizes $P$ and $P^{a^{-1}},$ so $P$ and $P^{a^{-1}}$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $C_G(V).$ Hence there is $b\in C_G(V)$ with $P^{a^{-1}}=P^b.$ That is, $P=P^{ba}.$ Then $ba\in N_{GA}(P)$ and $V^{ba}=V^a=W,$ as required.

Thanks @GeoffRobinson, I think we had the same idea. I've edited my (partial) answer to be slightly more assertive.

@ Tom WIlde , Thank you for your answer. Do you have any comment for the second part of question?

Without further conditions, the answer to the second part of the question is "no" in general. For example, we may take $G = A =Th$ (the sporadic simple group of Thompson) and $p=5$, $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then all subgroups of order $5$ in $P$ are conjugate in $G$ to $Z(P)$, but $P$ is extraspecial of order $125.$
Later edit: Thanks to @TomWilde for the correct definition of $2$-automorphic $2$-group. In the case $p=2$, we can take $G=A$ to be any simple group whose Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$ is dihedral (but not Klein 4). Then all involutions of $G$ are conjugate, but the automorphism group of $P$ is a $2$-group acting trivially on $Z(P)$, so is certainly not transitive on involutions of $P$. Also, $P$ is neither homocyclic nor generalized quaternion.
Even later edit: If the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is Abelian, and $A$ has order coprime to $p$, then it is true that $P$ is homocyclic under the hypotheses of the question, because in that case, a Hall $p^{\prime}$-subgroup of $N_{GA}(P)$ acts transitively on subgroups of order $p$ of $P$, so must be acting indecomposably on $P$.

I think perhaps a 2-automorphic 2-group is a 2-group whose automorphism group is transitive on its involutions, as defined in a paper of Fletcher Gross (https://zbmath.org/0341.20015). This does not affect your conclusion about the second part of the question, of course.

@TomWIlde : Thanks, but it does affect the Suzuki group examples, since the Sylow $2$ - normalizer acts transitively on involutions in these groups. But for $p=2$, according to your definition, any simple group with a dihedral (not Klein 4) Sylow $2$- subgroup will be a counterexample, since such groups have a single conjugacy class of involutions, but not all involutions are conjugate in the Sylow $2$-normalizer.

@Geoff Robinson : Thank you very much for your helpful comments.
